# How to Prevent multi tab in php

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have a website.
I want to prohibit visitors from having several tabs in their web browser.
can anybody help me to do this?

Comment: Not possible with PHP and hardly from any other language

Comment: Why would you ever prohibit visitors from having more than your tab open ?

Comment: because my server has limit Ram & CPU

Comment: This is a terrible idea. If you have limited CPU/RAM, get more CPU/RAM.

Answer (score 0):

1.The same problem (and solution) : https://sites.google.com/site/sarittechworld/track-client-windows

2.You cand send info`s by POST or GET

Comment: But I want solution on php.